# How many files are created when a C program is executed?

Tags: c

when we program in C language then how many files are created such as one ".exe" and an ".obj" is created. Any other files are created or not?
Thanks!

Comment: "Executed" or "compiled"?

Comment: suppose I write the program
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
printf("Hello World");
return 0;
}

and I run this program after compiling it see the output.
After all these number of files?
like as per my knowledge there will be an .exe any more files are ther?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer heavily depends on the specific compiler (gcc/msvc/clang), the version of that compiler, the architecture of the system, and whether you've asked the compiler to generate debugging information or not.  The [answer by @GrahamBorland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18933431/1430833) is correct in that `gcc test.c -o test` will create a net of only one file, `test`.  However, this is because `gcc` invokes both the compiler and linker and then deletes both temporary files and intermediate object files (.o) before returning.

During compilation, the compiler often generates several temporary files, which it then deletes to clean up.  Common ones are:

1. C compilers first run the code through a preprocessor, and often use a temporary file to store the result.
2. Almost all modern compilers reduce C to an intermediate language that can be better optimized.  This is often stored in a temporary file.
3. Old versions of gcc (possibly new versions, as well) would generate assembly, which was then assembled using `gas` (the GNU assembler).  This step was done using a temporary file (with a .S extension).

The result of the compile phase then produces either one or two files:

1. An object file (.o for most Unices, .obj for Windows) that contains compiled but unlinked code.  This code cannot be executed; it has external dependencies (the system library, and possibly other libraries) that must be satisfied by a linking phase.
2. If the user requests debugging information (`-g` under gcc), then, depending on the architecture and other compilation flags, the compiler may generate a file (or directory) that contains symbolic information used in debugging.  The compiler in Mac OS X produces .dSYM directories that contain the debugging information.  Under Linux, this is often embedded in the object (.o) file.

Finally, Mac, Unix, and Windows have a linking phase, which takes the object files (.o and .obj) and any required libraries (.a, and .so under Linux; .a, .dylib, or a framework under Mac OS X; .lib or .dll under Windows), and produces an executable.  This is the phase that generates the executable (.exe under Windows) file.

To sum it up, when compiling an executable:

- The C compiler often creates (and then deletes) a number of temporary files.
- The C compiler generates one or more object files.
- The linker generates an executable, and may also create (and delete) temporary files.
- Some C compilers (e.g., gcc) also operate as front-end drivers for both the compiler and the linker.  In this case, the compiler may delete any unneeded temporary files, such as the object files generated by the compilation phase.

Comment: very nice and elegant explanation. Really got glimpse of the comment. :)
Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure Mac uses `.dll` and `.so` ?

Comment: @0x90 Mac uses .dylib and no extension for libraries embedded in a framework (which is a directory with a .framework extension and a special structure).  I'll fix it.

Comment: @sfstewman great please ask to delete my comment when you done with it, however an awesome answer :)

Comment: Temporary files may be created, but it is not necessary. For example, gcc with `-pipe` flag will use pipes instead of temporary files.

Answer (score 3):

This depends entirely on the specific compiler, and how you are building your program. It is generally possible to compile and link your source directly to the executable in a single step.

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

No intermediate files will be left.

Comment: Here as per your command given what exactly happenning is first the gcc will compile and then create an object file named test and then we will run as ./test
Right?
Correct me if there is any mistake?

Comment: Yes. (You may need to set execute permission on the file before you can execute it.)

Comment: @SatishPatel Just to be pedantic, an object file is not an executable. An object file (.o or .obj) is compiled code with unsatisfied external dependencies,  Most of the functions declared in, for example, `stdio.h` are provided by a system library, and are listed as dependencies in the object file.  You have to link the object file with the system library (e.g., libc or the Windows system DLLs) and any other necessary library to resolve these dependencies before you get an executable. Here, `gcc` invokes both the compiler and linker to generate the executable `test`.

Comment: @sfstewman I never knew about this. By the way thanks for this knowledge. Got to know something new.
Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

When we run the C programme as

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    printf("hello");
}
```

then the compiler creates only `.bak` file. We can also get the source file from the `.bak` file.